# How to access an authentication token stored in a cookie set by a request to a different origin of future API requests?

Tags: javascript, cookies, single-sign-on

I'm looking into what it would take to create a Single Sign On application that can be used for apps that consist of static clients paired with separate APIs.

My (probably incorrect) understanding is that the flow of such a service works something like this:

**1**
A user asks for a static HTML / JavaScript resource from domain A

**2**
As the browser loads the static resource (an HTML page with inline JavaScript), An XHR request is made to Server B. Server B is an authentication server - it will look for a cookie in the request from the HTML page (origin A), and if it doesn't find one / or if the cookie does not contain a valid token, then it will send back an error

**3**
The JavaScript on the HTML page will see either success or error. If an error, the user will be redirected to a login page associated with server B, and with a URL param `redirect` that will allow the login page on server B to redirect back to server A on successful login: `server-b/login?redirect=server-a`

**4**
Then once a user has logged into server B, the JavaScript on the login page for server B will trigger a redirect back to server A (and the same static website will be returned as a result).

Then, as the HTML page returned from server A is loaded again, the XHR request to server B will be redone, but with a successful authentication message this time.

Using this approach. I don't see how I can access the authentication token provided by a cookie for the domain server B from a resource served by server A. This means that making XHR requests to my API from my static web page that I can't pass the authentication result of my interaction with server B.

But I COULD give the static page (served from server A) access to the cookie if that cookie were present in the URL as a param when the redirection from server B occurs.

Is this an acceptable way of implementing SSO?